# Why ajax reponse return whole php code not an echo variable

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have example code like this:

JQ:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'getData.php',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(123);
            console.log(data);
            console.log(123);
        }
    });
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$text = "hello";
echo $text;
?>
```

And I get all code like this

[image]

Why is not show 「hello」？

I run on Mamp, isn't work?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have your web server configured to run PHP code

Comment: What web server are you running?

Comment: Mamp, isn't work?

Comment: If you run `getData.php` from the browser directly what happens

Comment: @RiggsFolly  download this file.. ಠ_ಠ

Comment: Then your web server is not configured to run PHP code. I assume you have Apache as the server, so google how to configure PHP

Comment: May be simpler to reinstall MAMP so you get the latest versions of everything

Comment: @RiggsFolly Reboot my mac, it's work ಠ_ಠ .. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you have to use this in PHP:

```
<?php

$text = "hello";

echo json_encode($text);

?>
```

and you have to pass

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

Maybe it will helpful